# How to change default Validator Decoration controlsfx

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I use controlsfx in my project, and i tried to find proper way to change default validator decorations, so instead of graphic that it uses CSS decorator as default, but i had no access.

I have no problem to make my own decorator, and decorate some text field, (i define css class, create decorator and it works)

but how can i alter my code that it uses CSS decoration for validation as default!
Example code :

```
    ValidationSupport support = new ValidationSupport();
    public void isMax(TextField tf, Boolean b){
            Validator<String> validator = (control, value) -> {
            boolean condition =
                    value != null
                            ? !value
                            .matches(
                                    "[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(((((\\p{Digit}+)(\\.)?((\\p{Digit}+)?)([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(\\.((\\p{Digit}+))([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(((0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)(\\.)?)|(0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)?(\\.)(\\p{XDigit}+)))[pP][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+)))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*" )
                            : value == null;

            return ValidationResult.fromMessageIf(control,"not a number" ,Severity.ERROR , condition);
        };


        support.registerValidator( tf, b, validator );

    }
```

So what to change so my validation uses CSS styling instead graphic ones.

The code above works, and provides the graphic validation of text field, however the following does not work :

```
public class MyValid extends StyleClassValidationDecoration {


ValidationSupport support = new ValidationSupport();


    public void isMax(TextField tf, Boolean b){
      //  Decorator.addDecoration(tf,new StyleClassDecoration("warning"));
      support.setValidationDecorator(new StyleClassValidationDecoration());
            Validator<String> validator = (control, value) -> {
            boolean condition =
                    value != null
                            ? !value
                            .matches(
                                    "[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(((((\\p{Digit}+)(\\.)?((\\p{Digit}+)?)([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(\\.((\\p{Digit}+))([eE][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+))?)|(((0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)(\\.)?)|(0[xX](\\p{XDigit}+)?(\\.)(\\p{XDigit}+)))[pP][+-]?(\\p{Digit}+)))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*" )
                            : value == null;

            return ValidationResult.fromMessageIf(control,"not a number" ,Severity.ERROR , condition);
        };


        support.registerValidator( tf, b, validator );

    }
```

The problem is i think either that i dont know to point stylevalidation to coresponding css classes or the problem is in the line that returns ValidationResult.

For example this line of code :

```
Decorator.addDecoration(tf,new StyleClassDecoration("warning"));
```

decorates the field, and as a styling resources uses "warning" class in my default .css file.
How can i do this for StyleClassValidationDecoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reworking to show how to use a StyleClassValidtionDecoration.

In ControlsFX if using CSS - you can simply provide the StyleClassValidationDecoration the CSS classes you wish you use.

```
    ValidationSupport validator = new ValidationSupport();
    validator.setValidationDecorator(new StyleClassValidationDecoration("myErrorClass", "myWarningClass"));
    validator.registerValidator(fieldToValidate, false, this::myValidationForField);
```

Comment: This does not help, you are again making graphic validation decoration: i know how to create standard graphic validation, and it works, but css one does not work:

Comment: Can you extend - StyleClassValidationDecoration.java?

Comment: yes i can, i will edit the main question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use your style classes in the validation framework.